# Cast incoming $args as string value

Tags: powershell, args

My powershell script interfaces with an external program that sends varying number of arguments in the format

```
primary site=Peachtree Street
```

and is separated by commas

```
primary site=Peachtree Street, last logon=13 Nov 2013, sender-ip-10.10.10.10
```

I have been searching all over Internet how to cast $args as a string - otherwise $args removes the commas, and I need commas

Here is what I tried for $args

sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith

1st Script

```
write-host $args

$args = $args | Out-String

write-host $args
```

1st Output

```
sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
sender-ip=10.10.10.10
primary
site
location=peachtree
street
created
by=jsmith
```

2nd Script

```
write-host $args

$args = "'" + $args + "'"

write-host $args
```

2nd Output

```
sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
'System.Object[] site location=peachtree System.Object[] by=jsmith'
```

3rd Script

```
write-host $args

foreach ($i in $args){
   $i = $i | Out-String
}

write-host $args
```

3rd Output

```
sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
```

But how do I preserve the commas????

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote your input like

```
"sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith"
```

Commas are used for creating arrays, but with quotes around the text it will save everything as a single string.

Personally I'd also suggest that you avoid `args` and create a parameter instead so you could call it like `-paramtername "sender-ip=10.10.10.10, primary site location=peachtree street, created by=jsmith"`. Or at least use `$args[0]`. Things may break if someone forgets the quotes, since `$args` would then become an array.

UPDATE: This should work. However, it is a "dirty fix".

```
Write-Host (($args | % { $_ -join ", " }) -join " ")
```

Comment: But how do I quote my input? That is what I'm struggling with. An external program accesses the script and sends in varying number of argument, and the program just strips out the commas. If I was controlling the input then the problem is solved!

Comment: How does the progam access the script? Do you have any control over how it calls the PS script?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writig your script to take that as pipeline input instead of as arguments?

```
$script = @'
Begin{}
Process {$_}
End {}
'@

 $script | set-content testscript.ps1

 'primary site=Peachtree Street, last logon=13 Nov 2013, sender-ip-10.10.10.10' | ./testscript.ps1

primary site=Peachtree Street, last logon=13 Nov 2013, sender-ip-10.10.10.10
```

Then you're not subject to the argument parsing.

Comment: I never thought of that! Let me research, and I'll keep you posted. Thank you!!

Comment: It requires quotes in the sample script to create a string. Coming from the application program it will already be a string. It just doesn't get parsed into an argument array based on spaces in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't control your input, something like this may work to get you back to a comma separated list.

```
($args | select $_) -join ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks always seem to forget about the poor old output field separator variable `$OFS` e.g.:

```
C:\PS> function foo {$OFS=',';"$args"}
C:\PS> foo sender-ip=10.10.10.10 primary site location=peachtree street created by=jsmith
sender-ip=10.10.10.10,primary,site,location=peachtree,street,created,by=jsmith
```

Whatever string `$OFS` contains will be used between the elements of an array when it concatenated together to display as a string - typically when a variable containing an array is referenced inside a double-quoted string.